# Password hashes with large internal state

Tags: hash, password-cracking, memory, scrypt

scrypt was designed to use a lot of memory, and if all that memory wasn't used it would be some orders of magnitude slower to compute. Either way, it counters custom hardware attacks, where there tends to not be so much memory available.

I was thinking, why even bother allowing a time memory tradeoff? Wouldn't it be better to use a hash function with a very large (tuneable of course) internal state? The size of the internal state determines the memory requirements and the number of rounds is the work factor.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've described [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Instances), where the `capacity c` (and to a lesser extent, the `rate r`) are exactly the "very large (tuneable of course) internal state" you're talking about.

You don't have to crank it up very high (512 bits / 1024 bits) to get your 256 / 512 bit security levels.

Remember though that the goal of cryptography is not to make the attacker do a lot of work, it's to make the attacker do *a lot more work than than the legitimate user*. Hashing involves doing expensive operations on the internal state, so just blindly cranking up the size of the internal state hurts the legitimate user just as much as it hurts the attacker.

Large memory requirements of scrypt is meant to exploit a resource that's abundant to the legitimate user (a server handling a small number of login requests at a time), but scarce to the attacker running on massively parallelized hardware rigs.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "trade-off" for a reason. :)

As Mike Ounsworth suggests, there is asymmetry between the attacker and the legitimate user. But there is also asymmetry across *legitimate* use cases.

For example, your scrypt implementation might be tuned to authenticate a small percentage of your users in parallel during normal condition. But  if there is an outage or interruption such that all users are disconnected, and then (perhaps automatically) try to reconnect simultaneously? If that failure mode is a potential use case for your application, you might need to adjust your scrypt tunables accordingly.

But if you're only using scrypt to protect a single highly-sensitive encrypted volume on a personal system, then a delay of a few seconds might be acceptable to you - and desirable to increase the cost of an attack.

That's the tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, a time-memory tradeoff is an inevitable consequence of having a large internal state.  The folks over at [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) could probably come up with a more formalized explanation, but basically, if your password hash calls for computing, storing, and later using a large number of intermediate values, a memory-constrained attacker can always simply calculate those values on demand instead.